# Existing and existed

Tags: questions

Verb with ing and ed, if we use  such sentance " I have seen existing location which is at city mall"
"I have seen existed location which is at city mall"
Which of these sentences is correct. Are the either sentence correct if used as participle or will be different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the sentences is English, because you need articles.

However, "existed" cannot be used in this way. Forms in "-ed", which exist for most verbs, are called "past participles", and are used in two principal ways:

1. with a form of 'have', to form a perfect tense: _Cities have existed for ten thousand years"
2. adjectivally **with passive meaning** : *I have painted the wall* vs *There was a painted wall*.

But *exist* is intransitive, so you cannot form a passive meaning from it, so *existed* cannot be used in this adjectival way.

The "-ing" form, on the other hand, is called a "present participle", and when used adjectivally it is active in meaning, so *the existing location* makes perfect sense.

So *I have seen the existing location, which is at the city mall*. (unless "City Mall" is a name, in which case you don't need the second 'the').

Comment: Isn't *'existed'* just a past form of the word *"exist"*?

Comment: @SovereignSun: of course "existed" is the simple past of "exist", but that cannot be relevant here, because Meraj is trying to use it as a modifier to a noun phrase. That is possible for a past participle (which "existed" is), but generally only of a transitive verb.